# Combining rows without a unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I could use some help on developing a way to combine rows of data when the rows don't contain unique identifiers that the other rows reference. There is a pri_key, but the trailing rows never reference that key.

**Disclaimer:** I have no control over the design of the table. This is a query I'm running against a database of software we've purchased and have in production.

Here's a sample similar to the data I'm looking at:

```
pri_key   |   personID   |   Type   |   reference   |   details   |   date_time
101              1            A        Renewal #001   Trans # 001   2014-04-01 09:30:00
102              1            B        Modify  #001   Expires 30d   2014-04-01 09:30:00
104              1            A        Renewal #001   Trans # 002   2014-04-01 09:30:00
105              1            B        Modify  #001   Expires 60d   2014-04-01 09:30:00
108              2            A        Renewal #020   Trans # 003   2014-04-21 14:30:00
109              2            B        Modify  #020   Expires 45d   2014-04-21 14:30:00
111              3            A        Renewal #140   Trans # 004   2014-05-11 12:30:00
112              3            B        Modify  #140   Expires 90d   2014-05-11 12:30:00
```

There are hundreds more rows, some personID's have 4 rows, others have 2. There's always a B type row following an A type row and that's what I'm after. From what I can surmise, the pri_key always increases by 1 for the B type row, but there are gaps between pri_keys as seen in the sample. A and B also always have the exact same time stamp.

Using the sample above, here's what I'd like to see:

```
pri_key   |   personID   |   Type   |   reference   |   details   |   date_time         |   Modify    |   Expires
101              1            A        Renewal #001   Trans # 001   2014-04-01 09:30:00  Modify  #001    Expires 30d
104              1            A        Renewal #001   Trans # 002   2014-04-01 09:30:00  Modify  #001    Expires 60d
108              2            A        Renewal #020   Trans # 003   2014-04-21 14:30:00  Modify  #020    Expires 45d
111              3            A        Renewal #140   Trans # 004   2014-05-11 12:30:00  Modify  #140    Expires 90d
```

Essentially, I need the "expires" information from the B type's `details` to roll up into the A type's row. However, I'm getting caught on the peronID's that have 2 sets of rows. When I run various attempts at `JOIN` statements, I end up with a doubled up `Expires` column:

```
pri_key   |   personID   |   Type   |   reference   |   details   |   date_time         |   Modify    |   Expires
101              1            A        Renewal #001   Trans # 001   2014-04-01 09:30:00  Modify  #001    Expires 60d
104              1            A        Renewal #001   Trans # 002   2014-04-01 09:30:00  Modify  #001    Expires 60d
108              2            A        Renewal #020   Trans # 003   2014-04-21 14:30:00  Modify  #020    Expires 45d
111              3            A        Renewal #140   Trans # 004   2014-05-11 12:30:00  Modify  #140    Expires 90d
```

I'm currently thinking I need to find a way to use the `pri_key` +1 increments to my advantage, but I'm not sure that's the best approach or even how to properly handle that. Can anyone make any suggestions? I'm aware that what I've written here may make perfect sense to me and no one else, so please let me know if I can clarify. Thanks!

[I've created a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78286/1) with the sample data inserted if it's easier for anyone to reference that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The commented "and" clauses shouldn't be necessary (if what you've described is correct) and may make things slower, but you can include them to be safe. Without the commented stuff, this may be considerably faster than comparing based on type/person ID, and you don't have to worry about indexing those columns:

```
select a.*, b.reference as 'Modify', b.details as 'Expires'
from my_table a
join my_table b on a.pri_key = b.pri_key - 1
  -- and a.date_time = b.date_time
  -- and a.personid = b.personid
  -- and b.type = 'B'
where a.type = 'A'
```

Do you really need the "Modify" column?

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I need the column. The actual text in those columns is much more complex, I just put sample text in for brevity. Probably should have been clearer on that. I'll give this a shot and see how it goes. Makes sense though!

Comment: @BobbyScon: Yup. It's in the query.

Comment: Running on the SQL Fiddle, this appears to solve the problem (and is painfully obvious...Mondays!) I will run it against the live data to see if it holds up or if I missed any variables that could interfere with it. Thanks, Alvin!

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
SELECT 
  a1.pri_key, a1.personID, a1.Type, a1.reference, a1.details, a1.date_time, a2.reference as Modify, a2.details AS Expires  
FROM Activity AS a1 
LEFT JOIN activity as a2 on 
  a1.personid = a2.personid and 
  a1.pri_key+1 = a2.pri_key
WHERE  
  a1.type='A' and a2.type='B'
```

You need to name your join and then use that name to retrieve the information you want.

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78286/19).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'll give this a show and see how it goes.

Comment: If you're comparing based on a set of keys not explicitly guaranteed to be unique, you should include `and p1.date_time = p2.date_time` to be safer. It won't make things that much slower (if all these columns are indexed).

Comment: Also, I think you mean, `p2.reference as 'Modify', p2.details as 'Expires'`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work, even with Alvin's suggested modifications. Running this query on the SQL Fiddle I created returns 10 rows instead of just 4 as requested. I see what you're trying to do, but it's not quite right.

Comment: @BobbyScon: I think the issue is he's trying to use an outer join instead of an inner join. replace `left join` with `join`. Or just use mine which is faster. :)

Comment: @BobbyScon: I was completely wrong and Alvin completely right, sorry about that.  I fixed my answer and tested it with your fiddle.